# Bigquery dataset does not load

Tags: google-bigquery, google-compute-engine

I have some problems with Google BigQuery where one of our datasets does not load for me. It does load for my colleague, but never for me.

[image: postgres_tables do never load...]

I get a couple of errors in the developer console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

I get a couple of these errors. The middle one comes with some kind of link like this (where project_name is our Bigquery project)

> GET https://clients6.google.com/bigquery/v2/projects/project_name/datasets/postgres_tables/tables?maxResults=1000&key=AIzaSyDvB... net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

I guess this has something to do with the fact that every time I try to load BigQuery a small information box show saying `"Network unreachable. Dismiss"`

Any one had a similar problem and knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, it was caused by my ad blocker. All the datasets loaded well when I tried to disable it. You can add google to the allowlist of your ad blocker to solve the problem (ex: https://help.getadblock.com/support/solutions/articles/6000055743-how-to-disable-adblock-on-specific-sites)

Answer (score 1):

So I just tried to use BigQuery in Safari instead of Chrome, and that solved the whole problem!

Apparently there were additional data tables within other data sets that I didn't see either. Quite embarrassing that Google's own product doesn't work in Chrome but in Safari....

So if you experience the "Network Unreachable" bug, which prevent BigQuery to load all datasets and tables, use Safari instead!

Comment: Same here. Works in Microsoft Edge, but not in Chrome or Firefox. It says "Network unreachable".